# How to save Tensorflow Federated Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, federated-learning

How can I easily save a Tensorflow Federated model? (state)

A few months ago I was using this solution after importing **ServerState** and **FileCheckPointManager** and it worked:

```
# Create the checkpoint Manager
ckpt_manager = FileCheckpointManager(root_dir=checkpoint_dir)
# Save checkpoint for round N
ckpt_manager.save_checkpoint(ServerState.from_tff_result(state), round_num=NUM_ROUNDS)
```

But now this solution no longer works because [ServerState](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research/flars/flars_fedavg.py#L54) does not contain **`from_tff_result`** methotd anymore.

```
AttributeError: type object 'ServerState' has no attribute 'from_tff_result'
```

Also using the old version of ServerState where the metohd was included i get:

```
TypeError: Expected tensorflow_federated.python.common_libs.structure.Struct, found tensorflow_federated.python.learning.model_utils.ModelWeights.
```

How can I easly save my federated model?

Answer (score 0):

After a [recent change](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/commit/4ed574ab605cbf00eecd46729826f39729b64768) to prevent `Struct` (formerly `AnonymousTuple`) from being returned to users, there should *no longer* be any need for a method like `ServerState.from_tff_result(state)`; `state` should already  *be* a `ServerState`.

TLDR: if you update your example to simply read:

```py
# Create the checkpoint Manager
ckpt_manager = FileCheckpointManager(root_dir=checkpoint_dir)
# Save checkpoint for round N
ckpt_manager.save_checkpoint(state, round_num=NUM_ROUNDS)
```

it should just work.